# Mocking JavascriptDeserializer results in error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have created a wrapper over the `JavascriptDeserializer` to be able to Moq this.

This is my code:

```
public class JavaScriptSerializerWrapper: IJavaScriptSerializerWrapper
{
        public object Deserialize(string data)
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
            return serializer.Deserialize&lt;T&gt;(data); 
        }
}
```

Now in my unit tests I have tried to mock this like this:

```
private Mock<IJavascriptSerializerWrapper> m_JavascriptSerializerWrapper;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initializer()
{
    m_JavascriptSerializerWrapper = new Mock<IJavaScriptSerializerWrapper>();
}

[TestMethod]
public void Login_IsValidUser_ReturnsTrue()
{
    var deserializedObject = It.IsAny<EmployeeData>();

     m_JavascriptSerializerWrapper.Setup(x => x.GetJavascriptSerializer().Deserialize(userData)).Returns(deserializedObject);
}
```

I have debugged the unit test and I got this error of object reference is not an instance of an object.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `It.IsAny<>()` is an argument matcher not meant to be used outside of a Setup or Verify expression.

Comment: The interface in the example does not match the member setup in the test. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`It.IsAny<>()` is an argument matcher not meant to be used outside of a `Setup` or `Verify` expressions. If used, it will return the default value of the argument type, which in this case will be `null`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Login_IsValidUser_ReturnsTrue()
{
    var deserializedObject = new EmployeeData() {
        //...
    };

    m_JavascriptSerializerWrapper
        .Setup(_ => _.Deserialize(It.IsAny<string>())) //<-- note use of argument matcher
        .Returns(deserializedObject);

    //...
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart: Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)